# Consider defining a bean of type 'io.ipl.amaresh.data.JobCompletionNotificationListener' in your configuration. The bean could not be found in that

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-annotations

My Config class

```
package io.ipl.amaresh.ipldashboard.data;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import io.ipl.amaresh.data.JobCompletionNotificationListener;
import io.ipl.amaresh.ipldashboard.model.Match;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    private final String[] FIELD_NAMES = new String[] { "id", "city", "date", "player_of_match", "venue",
            "neutral_venue", "team1", "team2", "toss_winner", "toss_decision", "winner", "result", "result_margin",
            "eliminator", "method", "umpire1", "umpire2" };

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MatchInput>().name("MatchItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("match-data.csv")).delimited().names(FIELD_NAMES)
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MatchInput>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(MatchInput.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MatchDataProcessor processor() {
        return new MatchDataProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Match> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Match>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO match (id, city, date, player_of_match, venue, team1, team2, toss_winner, toss_decision, match_winner, result, result_margin, umpire1, umpire2) "
                        + " VALUES (:id, :city, :date, :playerOfMatch, :venue, :team1, :team2, :tossWinner, :tossDecision, :matchWinner, :result, :resultMargin, :umpire1, :umpire2)")
                .dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Match> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("step1")
            .<MatchInput, Match>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
}
```

My Listener class

```
package io.ipl.amaresh.data;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.JobExecutionListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.ipl.amaresh.ipldashboard.model.Team;

@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
      log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");
      
      Map<String, Team> teamData = new HashMap<>();
            
      em.createQuery("select m.team1, count(*) from Match m group by m.team1", Object[].class)
        .getResultList()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new Team((String) e[0], (long) e[1]))
        .forEach(team -> teamData.put(team.getTeamName(), team));
    
        em.createQuery("select m.team2, count(*) from Match m group by m.team2", Object[].class)
        .getResultList()
        .stream()
        .forEach(e -> {
            Team team = teamData.get((String) e[0]);
            team.setTotalMatches(team.getTotalMatches() + (long) e[1]);
        });

        em.createQuery("select m.matchWinner, count(*) from Match m group by m.matchWinner", Object[].class)
        .getResultList()
        .stream()
        .forEach(e -> {
            Team team = teamData.get((String) e[0]);
            if (team != null) team.setTotalWins((long) e[1]);
        });

        teamData.values().forEach(team -> em.persist(team));
        teamData.values().forEach(team -> System.out.println(team));
    }
  }
}
```

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method importUserJob in io.ipl.amaresh.ipldashboard.data.BatchConfig required a bean of type 'io.ipl.amaresh.data.JobCompletionNotificationListener' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'io.ipl.amaresh.data.JobCompletionNotificationListener' in your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you declare in your config that you need a `JobCompletionNotificationListener` in following lines:

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, ...)
```

But you never declare how to build/retrieve such a component in your config.

Depending on your usage of Spring, **you need to include `JobCompletionNotificationListener` in the context**: explicit `@Bean`, package scanning..

EDIT: Notice that auto detection won't work here as your `BatchConfig` is in a subpackage compare to your `@Component` bean. AFAIK Spring auto detection only looks in current package.

Comment: I have added @Component to the listener class. Isn't that supposed to automatically detect the beans?

Comment: It could but notice that here your `BatchConfig` is in a subpackage compare to your `@Component` bean. AFAIK Spring auto detection only looks in current package.

Comment: Resolved. Had to put it into the same package as you said. Thank you so much Gael J.